# How to call ansible playbook in terraform code?

Tags: ansible, terraform, provisioning

I have an ansible playbook which works well , now I have to call that playbook using terrform scripts. Currently I m using code which is shown below but it results in error during terraform init as:
`Error: Unknown root level key: provisioner`

I am using Terraform v0.11.7 and the error occurs only when I run this specific code. 
Also my main.tf consists of only this code. The directory structure I have used is such as :

```
.
├── create-user.yml
├── library
│   └── mkpassword.py
├── main.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── roles
│   └── linux_user_creation
│       └── tasks
│           └── main.yml
└── variables.tf
```

main.tf looks like :

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = ["sudo dnf -y install python"]

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file(var.ssh_keyname)}"
  }
}

provisioner "remote-exec" {
  command = ["ansible-playbook -u root --private-key ${var.ssh_keyname} -i ${self.ipv4_address} create-user.yml -e 'email_id=${var.email_id}'"]
}
```

I expect the playbook should be called from the terraform scripts and should display the results.

Comment: The provisioner must be part of another resource such as an `aws_instance` resource or even the `null_resource` resource if there isn't one that makes sense. It would be helpful to answerers if you showed your full Terraform code so they can explain more fully how this should work.

Comment: Hello @ydaetskcoR I have updated main.tf and I have not added any resource because I am creating resources with other tf .

Comment: You may want to checkout the Ansible provisioner plugin for Terraform. https://github.com/radekg/terraform-provisioner-ansible In addition, I have written an article about using it which could be helpful for you https://medium.com/@robinflume/about-infrastructure-on-aws-automated-with-terraform-ansible-and-gitlab-ci-5888fe2e85fc

Comment: @rflume Thankyou so much but do you think the above code looks fine? Not sure why but everything is run `provisioner "remote-exec" ` module , it returns me error as : **Unknown root level key: provisioner**

Comment: If that's all your Terraform and you aren't actually using Terraform to create a resource somewhere what are you connecting to and why do you need Terraform at all instead of just running Ansible directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code snipped form `main.tf` is not complete. Could you post the full resource definitions in which you run the `remote-exec` provisioners please?

An what should the Ansible playbook do? Create a user on the remote host itself? Or is it just a host where your Ansible scripts are stored, and the user is actually created on another remote host from there?

As @ydaetskcoR mentioned, you need to run this code within a `null_resource`:

```
resource null_resource "provisioner" {
  connection {
    ... # set the connection parameters here
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    command = ["ansible-playbook -u root --private-key ${var.ssh_keyname} -i ${self.ipv4_address} create-user.yml -e 'email_id=${var.email_id}'"]
  }
}
```

I'd however suggest to install the Ansible provisioner, as already mentioned in the comment above. This way you'd bundle the Ansible playbook directly with your Terraform code and do not need to connect to some other instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @rflume . Basically ansible playbook is creating users on the remote machine. If I use remote-exec it doesnt work and gives me error like "command is not a valid key attribute" but it doesnt give any such error while running on local-exec but doesnt give me the desired output though.

Comment: Have you tried changing `command` to `inline` as stated in the Docs (https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html)?