# Ansible calling Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform

If I would create an infrastructure on AWS by using `Terraform` and configure the created resources by `Ansible`. What is the best way to retreive the information of these resources and pass them to Ansible (to be configured) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call ansible playbook in terraform code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315955/how-to-call-ansible-playbook-in-terraform-code)

Comment: You can also use `terraform` local-exec to write any necessary data about the resources you create and use them with `ansible`

Comment: Yes ! Thank you for your answers. Following redhat documentary, the best way to combine terraform and ansible is by invoking local-exec and remote-exec.
For the futur readers, read this documentation https://www.redhat.com/cms/managed-files/pa-terraform-and-ansible-overview-f14774wg-201811-en.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Terraform Output Values can be defined to pass data back to the calling application, and can alternatively be queried directly from the current state after a Terraform Apply.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/aws-outputs
https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html